# sqlite.swift database table is locked (code:6)

Tags: swift, sqlite, sqlite.swift

I am trying to create a project that will sync data from an online database.

I have 4 files to take care of the whole process:

1. dbConnection.swift
2. createTables.swift
3. dropAllTables.swift
4. updateDatabase.swift

I am running into a problem when trying to drop the tables.

For example I have a table named `FLEET_GROUPINGS_FOR_IPAD_SYSTEM` in a function in `createTables.swift`.

The following code (in a separate function in `dropAllTables.swift`):

```
let table = Table("FLEET_GROUPINGS_FOR_IPAD_SYSTEM")
try db.run(table.drop())
```

throws this error:

```
database table is locked (code: 6)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This finally worked for me, close the connection manually after each read/write operation: db = Connection(). This is a messy solution as sqlite.swift was meant to close its connections automatically but I was getting this problem because I was defining my connection as a separate function. I wouldn't recommend this, best to define connections at the start of each file when they're needed.

Answer (score 0):

try to run all your tables related data in a single thread with synchronization

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).sync 
           {
             try db.run(table.drop())
           }
```

Comment: This almost did it, although I was still getting the same issue. The fix was to manually close the database after each operation by assigning the db to an empty connection: 

db = Connection()